# Can we use keras VGG16 model with vgg_face_weights.h5 weights file?

Tags: keras, face-detection

I am trying to use VGG16 model from keras library. I want to use the model to detect faces. I am also using the vgg_face_weights.h5 file for loading weights for the model.

But it gives error as "ValueError: Cannot assign value to variable ' fc1/kernel:0': Shape mismatch.The variable shape (25088, 4096), and the assigned value shape (7, 7, 512, 4096) are incompatible."

**Following is the code:**

from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras .applications import VGG16

base_model = VGG16(input_shape=(224, 224, 3),include_top=True)

base_model.load_weights('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Project_Data/CV/vgg_face_weights.h5')

Can we not use vgg_face_weights.h5 file with VGG16 model from Keras? Is this weight file not meant for this model? If not, which pre-trained model can we use with this weight file?